# get post_type in WordPress plugin to call some code

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using event plugin of WordPress. Now i am making custom plugin to add some additional functionalities.

What i want is to, when I publish any event ( which is actually a post with post_type = ajde_events)

I want to get this post type in my plugin. So that :

```
if(post_type=ajde_events)
{
// Then do some thing 
}
else {
// NO
}
```

Right now i have tried 
$_POST['post_type'] in my plugin. I can see in inspect element there is hidden field with this name and with this value ajde_events. But it's isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You said it in your title...use [get_post_type()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type):

```
if ( get_post_type() == 'ajde_events' )
{
  // Then do some thing 
}
else {
  // NO
}
```

Comment: I need it in Admin Section.